# TeamCity can't find NAnt

Tags: nant, teamcity

I am trying to call a NAnt script from TeamCity, but I'm encountering something that makes no sense to me.

I've tested the NAnt script from the command line and it works perfectly.

I've configured the NAnt build runner in TeamCity, and when I run it, I get the following error:

```
Step 3/3
The following paths do not contain NAnt:
C:\nant\bin
C:\TeamCity6\buildAgent\work\59c8c293c5dec971\C:\nant\bin
Please check "NAnt home" parameter at the build runner settings page
```

I've checked many times that the NAnt executable resides in C:\nant\bin

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure the user that team city is running as has permission to that file...

Answer (score 0):

You should have everything you need to build your project (NAnt included) in your repository (Eg. in `build\tools` folder). Everyone should be able to build after check-out without installing tools.

Comment: this convention does not suit every team